# Asynchronous CompletableFuture returning synchronously to single thread ExecutorService

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, java-8, executorservice, completable-future

I am creating a **single thread ExecutorService** and assign tasks *(CompletableFuture)*, required to be executed Asynchronously (tried both runAsync and supplyAsync), to that single thread service.

```
package Executor;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ExecutorResolver {

    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    volatile int counter = 2;
    static int ten = 10;
    static int five = 5;

    public void printer() {

        System.out.println("This thread is complete :" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    }

    public void execute() {

        CompletableFuture<Void> ct = CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread t = new Thread();
                Thread.sleep(ten * 1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, es).thenRunAsync(this::printer), CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread t = new Thread();
                Thread.sleep(five * 1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, es).thenRunAsync(this::printer)

        );

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ExecutorResolver er = new ExecutorResolver();

        er.execute();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            System.out.println("Current thread name : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + i);
        }
        System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    }

}
```

But they are getting executed synchronously ,

[See the console log which waits for thread that sleeps for 10 secs and then the executes the one which sleeps for 5 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbvuL.png)

Please let me know if this is possible or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: How do you want to run two different pieces of code in parallel if you only have one thread?

Comment: These `Thread t = new Thread();` lines have no effect. The newly constructed threads have no associated action to perform and are never started anyway. What do you expect from these lines?

Comment: @SpiderPig : I dont want them to run in parallel, consider them as a web service call, just wanted the two activities to differ in their return time, like the one that is started first ,with 10 secs sleep, should return after the second, with 5 secs sleep.

Comment: @Holger: Sir, may be they don't have effect , may be i am missing some part, all i want to do is

Comment: There are only parallel or sequential execution, nothing else. In your question you are complaining that the execution is “synchronously”, which is the same as “sequential” or “not parallel”. In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355409/?noredirect=1#comment79695231_46355409), you are saying that you “dont want them to run in parallel”, which would imply that you don’t have problem, as they are already not running in parallel. But then, you are saying that you want the sleep times to overlap, expecting the earlier started job to return later, which *is* parallel execution.

Comment: @Holger: Sir, may be i am missing some part, all i want to do is 1) create two async jobs and give them the executor service handle , 2) who ever returns first should be able to invoke/wake up the single thread executor service. I created two separate threads to create an async event, where i was expecting completableFuture to know that my current activity has nothing to do so i can pick up something else, but as the screenshot proves it considers a sleeping Thread to be a current activity,, please let me know where am i short in my understanding.

Comment: First of all, as already said, writing `Thread t = new Thread();` somewhere has no effect at all. Second, your “async” jobs are *executed* by the specified *executor*, that’s what an *executor* is about, as its name suggests. There is no such thing as “waking up an executor service”. Since the executor is single threaded, the jobs are executed single threaded, one after the other. Third, no, a completable future is not able to magically find out that you are wasting the thread by calling `sleep`. You have one thread and you let that one thread sleep. And a sleeping thread sleeps, nothing else.

Comment: @Holger : thanks for pointing out the problem! I was able to fix this code. But it's to be seen that "What actually is an async task for Completable Future" , will it be able to detach itself from a long running web service call or an I/O task, as happens in an actual environment? I will try out that now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is use a single threaded asynchronous programming style. That style is heavily used in Javascript especially node.js applications because it is really well suited for serverside code that has to handle many clients at once which is very well explained in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ztspvPYybIY) by the creator of node.js. In the Java world however, that programming style is not very widespread for some reason. So maybe you want to learn node.js programming first. Afterwards you can translate the things you learned there to Java.
Anyway, I changed your code and I think it is now doing what you intended. The problem is that you can't perform a delay by blocking your thread. Instead you have to use a Future for that as well.

```
package executor;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ExecutorResolver {
    private final ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private static final Timer timer = new Timer();

    public static CompletableFuture<Void> delay(long delay) {
      CompletableFuture<Void> fut = new CompletableFuture<>();
      timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          fut.complete(null);
        }
      }, delay);
      return fut;
    }

    public static Date date() {
      return new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public void execute() {
        CompletableFuture<Void> ct = CompletableFuture.allOf(
            CompletableFuture
                .runAsync(() -> {
                    System.out.println(date() + ": started first async operation in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
                }, es)
                .thenComposeAsync(x -> delay(10000), es)
                .thenRunAsync(() -> {
                  System.out.println(date() + ": completed first async operation in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
                }, es)
            ,

            CompletableFuture
                .runAsync(() -> {
                    System.out.println(date() + ": started second async operation in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
                }, es)
                .thenComposeAsync(x -> delay(5000), es)
                .thenRunAsync(() -> {
                  System.out.println(date() + ": completed second async operation in thread " + Thread.currentThread());
                }, es)
          );
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ExecutorResolver er = new ExecutorResolver();
        er.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: I indeed was trying to do that, I have worked with node.js and was trying to achieve the callback functionality within the same (you can call it event loop) single thread. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: btw. you don't need the line `CompletableFuture<Void> ct = CompletableFuture.allOf(`. You would only need it if you wanted to do something once both futures are finished.

Comment: Then how can I create a pipeline (or how can I simply assign a listener to my ES which gets to know which of the completableFuture has returned)? Also in this case we are deliberately creating an async scenario. In actual world what are the factors that let ES decide that a method is unresponsive , for eg: a large file read by NIO? most importantly a web service that takes long time to respond?

Comment: What do you mean by pipeline? You already have a pipeline here don't you? Or actually two pipelines in this code example. To detect unresponsiveness there is the method `orTimeout` but it was only introduced in Java 9.